# VB.NET 2017 - Increment textbox value from database to +1 when button clicked

Tags: vb.net

I get this code somewhere to increment/initialize id for specific table.

```
Sub loadID()
        Try
            DbConnect()
            Dim query As String = "SELECT res_id from residence ORDER BY res_id DESC LIMIT 1"
            ExecuteQuery(query)
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While reader.Read
                    txtCitID.Text = "RES" & Val(Mid(reader.GetString(0), 4, 8)) + 1
                End While
            Else
                txtCitID.Text = "RES20001"
            End If
            DbDisconnect()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured." & ex.Message)
        Finally
            DisposeConnection()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Assuming my current textbox value is RES20001. I wish to increment the value everytime i clicked the button to transfer the id into listview and so on. Specifically, i'm adding multiple data with different id(incremented) into listview to save it as one into database. Tried with the basics " +1 " method and other, but i cant get it right :(

Comment: Unless that ExecuteQuery() is overloaded, it will force you to write code that is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: oh xD that thing is just actually a 
```
command = New MySqlCommand(query, connect)
reader = command.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: If you want to increment database values by 1 then you should be using a database sequence. That's a feature provided by MySQL to do exactly what you want to do so you should use it.

Comment: Yeeeaah... you need more than that. What you have now will force you to use string concatenation to include user-supplied information in queries, which is **REALLY REALLY DANGEROUS**. Google "parametered queries", and _don't do anything else_ until you're able to build an `ExecuteReader()` that will use parameters. It's that's important. This is one of those things that too important to get wrong even in learning/proof of concept code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, parameterising queries is important but there's no user input in this case and not even a `WHERE` clause, so there's no need for parameters. It would be the subsequent `INSERT` that would require the parameters.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Correct, no user input in this case. But with that `ExecuteReader()` method in the data layer, it's impossible to have any safe SQL in the application that will incorporate user input.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, you're right. You've incorrectly said `ExecuteReader` the last two times, which threw me a bit, but you correctly said `ExecuteQuery` the first time. As you say, if that method is not overloaded to provide a means to pass in parameters, which I see in so many DALs, then it's a huge security risk and more.